# Random Forest Overfitting, issues with mtry=1?

Tags: classification, r, random-forest, overfitting

I am constructing what is known as an 'Expected Goals' model for football. This metric measures shot quality and a probability is assigned to a shot to achieve this, i.e. the chance a shot will be converted. To create this model I am using a random forest classifier. For evaluation purposes I am only interested in the accuracy of the probabilities rather than strictly classifying shots, therefore, I use the predictions to calculate the Mean Square Error where goal = 1 and no goal = 0. The MSE for the test set along with two benchmarks are as follows:

```
[1] "test.rf_mse: 0.0856633533734135"
[1] "comparison_model_mse: 0.0820007160001345"
[1] "naive_baseline_mse: 0.0912291249164997"
```

Note that the comparison model should be better than mine but the naive baseline should be worse. When looking at this the model looks to be doing okay. However, when I apply the same steps to the training set I get the following:

```
[1] "test.rf_mse: 0.0112001023587005"
[1] "comparison_model_mse: 0.0722459417565357"
[1] "naive_baseline_mse: 0.0858344459279039"
```

Here the MSE falls to unrealistic levels. Doesn't this mean that my model is overfitting? I understand that the idea that random forests can't overfit isn't strictly correct as all models can overfit to some extent, but for the model to be overfitting by this much must mean I am misunderstanding something here.

```
#FINAL MODEL FOR SHOTS DATASET
set.seed(5555)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(shots$goal.miss, p = .75, list = FALSE)
train_set <- shots[ trainIndex,]
test_set  <- shots[-trainIndex,]

set.seed(1000)
rf.shots <- randomForest(as.factor(goal.miss) ~ ., data=train_set, ntree=500, mtry=5)

###TEST RESULTS
pred <- predict(rf.shots, test_set, type="prob")
test_set$predictions.test <- pred[,2]
mean(((test_set$goal.miss - test_set$predictions.test)^2))

###TRAIN RESULTS 
pred <- predict(rf.shots, train_set, type="prob")
train_set$predictions.train <- pred[,2]
mean(((train_set$goal.miss - train_set$predictions.train)^2))
```

**NOTE: I moved on to using the 'ranger' random forest package which allowed me to tune more hyperparameters. From a grid search, I found the only parameter that appeared to cause overfitting was mtry. I could remove overfitting by setting mtry to 1. However, having mtry at one does not minimise the MSE for the test_set and I have 29 features in the model meaning the default mtry should be 5. Therefore, I believe I must have some issues with my feature selections that is causing the overfitting. Either that or there are circumstances whereby mtry-1 is optimal? But I am not convinced by that.**

Comment: It's a bit of a guess since I don't know R but is the very last line of your code ```mean(((test_set$goal.miss - test_set$predictions.train)^2))```  really correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes that was a typo. I was trying to make the code look clearer on here but messed up. I've correct the code to how it should be. I have moved onto the 'ranger' package which is a bit smarter and allows me to tune for hyperparameters. I found that the only parameter that appeared to cause overfitting was mtry and I could remove the overfitting by setting mtry = 1. However, I have 29 features so the default would be 5, so I think I have some issues with my feature selection

Comment: What is the "naive baseline" model?

Comment: The naive baseline model simply assigns a probability of 10% to every shot.

Comment: Reducing the tree depth doesn't help?

Comment: I tuned min.node.size to reduce the depths of the trees as this is what the 'ranger' package allows for. Initially, I tuned it up to 30 (from 1) and it made no difference but I re-tuned with values up to 100-200 and it appears to have worked. I can select the model with the min test_mse and obtain an mtry that isn't 1, as well as, having a seemingly reasonable train_mse compared to before, so I think that was the issue. The difference between two errors is still minimised when mtry = 1 but maybe that's irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the bagging of random forests is meant to reduce overfitting, they generally will overfit more than e.g. a parametric model like logistic regression.

Having a larger gap between training and testing scores is not *necessarily* a problem; you may still prefer the model if its testing score is higher than other models'.  In a purely statistical perfect world, the test score is all you should care about.  In real problems, there are some other things to consider: a more-overfit tree model is likely less interpretable, potentially takes longer to train and make predictions, may be more susceptible to concept drift, etc.

You should, as you have, see if reducing the model's capacity can increase your testing score (and maybe see if doing so can reduce the train-test gap even if it costs a little on test score, see above).  With `min.node.size`, I would suggest using a fraction of the training set size rather than the small fixed integers that are default in `ranger`.  Note that `ranger` does also have a `max.depth` parameter if you'd prefer to fix that directly.  Reducing `mtry` is also a good approach, but 1 strikes me personally as too random, and I'd worry that you'd need a ton of trees to stabilize results; using `mtry` in combination with a tree complexity parameter hopefully produces a higher test score without too outrageous of a train-test gap.